# Как увидеть список всех запущенных виртуальных окружений?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, virtualenv

Есть удаленный сервер. Подключился к нему по SSH через Putty. Запустил virtualenv проекта на питоне.

Запустил нужные скрипты, отправил их в фон (находясь в виртуальном окружении). Закрыл соединение.

Скрипты работают (я вижу, так как речь идет о боте для телеграмма и он прекрасно делает то, что ему сказано).

Захожу на сервер. Виртуального окружения уже не вижу, а значит, что `jobs` ничего не показывает. Фоновых процессов будто нет (ессена, я же запускал их, находясь в виртуальном окружении).

Как мне теперь вернуться именно к тому окружению, в котором фоном висят задачи?

Установил `virtualenvwrapper`, но `lsvirtualenv` (список окружений) ничего не показывает.

Comment: Используйте специально предназначенные для этого утилиты типа screen, supervisor и подобные

Comment: как бы вы увидели запущенный  вне virtualenv python процесс? Несколько предпосылок в вопросе неверны. Похоже на XY задачу. Что вы хотите сделать "вернувшись именно к тому окружению"?

Comment: @jfs, что не так с условием? Запустил виртуальное окружение, в нем запустил парочку скриптов в фоновом режиме. Закрыл соединение, но бот (а значит и скрипты, крутящиеся в фоне, в  виртуальном окружении, продолжают работать. Открыв соединение опять, виртуального окружения я не вижу, но то, что в нем запущено - работает. Как открыть это окружение?

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, я посмотрю. Но сейчас нужно именно так, как в вопросе..

Comment: @jfs я не хочу увидеть запущенный вне virtualenv python процесс. Я хочу вернуться в virtualenv в котором эти скрипты крутятся после закрытия соединения и открытия его заново. Вернувшись к нему, хочу запустить еще один и посмотреть логи..

Comment: 1- я вас не спрашивал хотите или не хотите. Вопрос был намёк, что абсолютно те же меры, которые бы вам позволили бы увидеть python процесс, запущенный вне virtualenv работают и для  python процесса, запущенного в virtualenv.  2- Чтобы запустить python процесс в virtualenv или логи посмотреть, вовсе не нужно к существующей сессии подсоединяться.

Comment: @jfs извините, но то ли я совсем зеленый, то ли мы друг друга не понимаем. Я могу создать хоть тысячу виртуальных окружений и запускать в них все, что нужно. Но закрыв соединение в них я уже не знаю как попасть. А нужно попасть КОНКРЕТНО в то окружение, которое работает и в котором запущены скрипты, которые что-то там могли вывести в консоль этого окружения. Т.е. мне нужно наоборот увидеть процесс скрипта, который находятся в виртуальном окружении, находясь вне виртуального окружения. Спасибо за терпение)

Comment: Понятия «работает какое-то виртуальное окружение» не существует. Оно существует только в вашей консоли, которую вы давным-давно закрыли. Для процессов, которые остались работать в фоне, виртуальное окружение — это всего лишь изменённый PYTHONPATH/sys.path/site_packages и тому подобные мелкие вещи. Никаких отличий процессов, запущенных в виртуальном окружении, от процессов, запущенных не в нём, нет. Вы никак не можете подключиться к работающему виртуальному окружению, потому что оно не существует.

Comment: @IvanBlohin если для себя на коленке, то можете отключаться/подключаться к терминалам используя упомянутый screen, tmux.

Comment: @IvanBlohin, вам пытаются намекнуть, что может стоит добавить logging в файл(ы). Тогда вам не нужно будет подключаться к сессиям запущенных демонов